# can php communicate with a software installed on my server?

Tags: php, web-hosting

suppose i have my own servers for my site and i want to make a site that can convert .doc documents to pdf (this is just an example.i want to do many other things).i have a doc to pdf converter software installed on the server .can i use php to make a site that receives the user's input file , sends the file to the software and receives the output pdf file which is finally sent to the user to download. can i do this? if yes then how?

if this can be done then can i also do it by using a web hosting company instead of my own servers?

Comment: suppose it depends on what OS you are running but you can use www.php.net/exec to execute command-line code, or if your OS/program is windows-based you might be able to make use of www.php.net/COM

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do this via PHP's [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. What you're allowed to execute will depend on the server you're running PHP on. Also, be careful about what you execute. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes.

The most straightforward way is using one of the [program execution functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) like `exec()`. Those are probably what you want. There are also more specialized, more seldom used ways [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php).

Whether your hosting company allows executing programs is a different matter - most have these functions blocked for security reasons, because you usually share a server with many other web sites. You'll have to ask your provider to make sure.